# Unable to run Qt applications in Windows

Tags: c++, qt, dll, mingw, dependency-walker

I created an executable of the default MainWindow (changed no code whatsoever) with MinGW GCC, and moved the .exe file from the debug directory to another directory in which I have **QtCored4.dll**, **QtGuid4.dll**, and **QtNetworkd4.dll**.

When I click on the executable, I get the error message:

> The procedure entry point _ZN7QWidget8winEventEP6tagMSGPI could not be located in the dynamic link library QtGuid4.dll.

Opening my executable with Dependency Walker gives me the following notifications:

> Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
>   Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found.
>   Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

I really don't know where I'm going wrong, and would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: You you verify that the checksums on the Qt dll's are the same?

Comment: Where did you get the DLLs from? If you built them yourself, what is the configuration? And which settings were used to build the executable?

Comment: I've never been able to create a stand-alone executable file using Qt... I'd love to know how to do it if you find out. I've been told you need a license.

Comment: To me it looks like you have Qt dlls from either a different compiler or different version of Qt.

Comment: @NekkoRivera you can compile a stand-alone executable without purchasing a commercial license but your program will have to be distributed under the same license as the Qt libraries: the LGPL. You're allowed to "dynamically link" your proprietary program to Qt libraries, since the LGPL is meant to allow proprietary apps to USE open source libraries.

Comment: So what is the easiest way to run the executable? I don't plan on distributing. I just want to have a shortcut on my personal laptop (which is where the project is) that runs my program without having to open the project in Qt and run it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either miss a DLL that is dynamically loaded by QtGuid4.dll (dependency walker should indicate that), or that DLL misses symbols because it is compiled with a a different configuration. Is your executable compiled with debug settings, like the DLLs are? Do you have the "normal" DLLs (no 'd') around, too?